# Why is Stack Overflow creating a new user when I try to log in?

Tags: support, login

When I go to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/login` it automatically takes me to a page that displays my email and says: Confirm to create account. I don't want this, I just want to login. I can't find any way of logging in without this displaying. I think the problem might be something with that I normally use Google to login.

Comment: Are there no other buttons, fields, etc. on the page? Does it do this in every browser you try?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to have three accounts - two with different Gmail addresses, and one with a different email provider that you could access via the "log in with Stack Exchange" option.

Chances are, you're choosing the wrong Gmail address when logging in. To fix this, log out completely (via the right-most button in the top bar) and *then* log in again.

If you'd like these accounts to be merged, use the /contact link at the bottom of the page.